# Get text value of input from FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know now normally you can get the value of a text input using the following:

```
txtName.Text
```

But because my input is inside of a LoginView I am using FindControl like this:

```
LoginView1.FindControl("txtComment")
```

This successfully find the text input but returns its type rather than the value.  Adding the Text function at the end does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try casting that `Control` to `TextBox`. `FindControl` returns a `Control` which doesn't have the `Text` property

```
TextBox txtName = LoginView1.FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox;
if (txtName != null)
{
    return txtName.Value;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that if it is a `TextBox`, then it *does* return a control that doesn't have the `Text` property, it just so happens that the type of the *reference* doesn't have the property.

Comment: It's actually interesting not to cast as a TextBox, but rather as an ITextControl because it has the Text property, but it supports more controls, so the code is more robust.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while since I used the controls, but i believe it is:

```
string text = ((TextBox)LoginView1.FindControl("txtComment")).Text;
```